# Protecting mongodb database against query injection in email submission

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, mongodb-query, sql-injection

I'm programming my first API with node.js and a mongodb database and I'm concerned about security.

In the code I have this line :

```
collection.count({email: req.body.email})
```

and this one :

```
collection.insert(req.body)
```

where ***req.body*** is a user object sent by the user with his infos (email, name, hashed password...).
I red that it is dangerous to parse what the user send.

Does ***req.body.email*** count as parsing ?
If yes I would like to sanitize it before the request with **mongo-sanitize** but looking at its code, it seems that it deletes "." and "$" which are both authorized characters for an email adress.

So my question is : *how can one store an email address securely without loosing information ?*

(if I sanitize "surname.name@gmail.com", I get "namesurname@gmailcom" and I can't retrieve the address without a previous fastidious storing of an array containing the position and type of forbidden characters)

Comment: I suggest regular expression matching on the client. Often times you would want to ensure that any data going to the server is in a valid state before processing it. That way you know that when you query for anything you don't have as much filtering and processing, you just retrieve and send back more efficiently and with less concern. But of course you may want to verify on the server if there isn't any authentication to post to that particular end point but RegEx can still be used on the server as well.

Comment: I don't see how securing what the client send will help with security, the attacker can still **curl** his way into my db right ? Thanks for RegEx it seems like it's a great tool.